# Making a div bounce every 2 seconds on loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQuery UI -- I have the bounce on page load, one time; working properly. But I am seeking to have this occur every 2 seconds on loop, for as long as the user is on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(".test").effect( "bounce", 
              {times:4}, 2500 );

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
setInterval(function() 
    {
      $(".test").effect( "bounce", 
          {times:4}, 2500 );
     },2000);
```

Your function will be execute in every two seconds. But your effect needs `2.5 seconds`.I guess it would be better if you set your interval to `3000` milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I would use some Javascript setInterval:

```
$document.ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
  //your effect
  }, 2000);
});
```